# PHP require variable from php file

Tags: php

How can I make a config.php file with all environment variables and import it successfully into other scripts?

config.php:

```
<?php
    $folder = 'SomePath';
?>
```

script1.php

```
<?php
    require_once('config.php');
    function doStuff(){
        global $folder;
        echo($folder);
    }

    doStuff();
?>
```

I get

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: folder in script1.php
```

It's php version `5.4.41` and I can't do anything about it (no root)

Comment: see edit, typo here, not in my script

Comment: is config.php in the same folder with script1.php ?

Comment: yes, it' in the same folder

Comment: 100% valid, something your not showing is going on

Comment: Is script1.php included by another script?

Comment: See new edit, works. Why do I have to put require into the function body? I didnt realize there was a difference. Thought of require as include in C...

Comment: you are not calling the function, that's why it doesn't give you the error now.

Comment: im so sick of people not posting their real code, sigh

Comment: Do `echo getcwd();` in script1.php and see if it is the directory that config.php is in.

Comment: @Dagon, why post the full code that would reveal confidential info?

Comment: Can somebody please answer why I had to put `require_once` into the function body instead to the top level? Why would `$folder` be unknown in the `doStuff` function?

Comment: because variables are not global, functions have their own scope (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959576/reference-what-is-variable-scope-which-variables-are-accessible-from-where-and)

Comment: There is no reason why you had to put `require_once` into the function body. From the code you posted, it should work.

Comment: how would I define global variables in config.php with PHP then? I looked at this example http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php and why doesnt it apply?

Comment: @Andrew yes there is, **varable scope**, if included out side the function the, the function would not see the variable inside the include

Comment: @Dagon yes but in the first version of his question, he didn't have a function.

Comment: @Andrew but thats not his code, he expects us to psychiclly guess what code he has

Comment: @Andrew That was my mistake. Sorry. I didnt realize the scope in a function would be clean. But it contradicts the example I posted above

Comment: nothing in the manual page is wrong, i dont see why your not getting this

Comment: Oh ok then Dagon is correct, your functions can't see global variables.

Comment: @Dagon Well, guess that was my problem all along. If I move `require_once` out of `doStuff`, it fails again...

Comment: yes, because the variable is outside the function scope.

Comment: But what's the difference between my code now and http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php ? Why should it work for the tutorial example and fails for my particular example?

Comment: are we looking at the same manual page : **This script will not produce any output because the echo statement refers to a local version of the $a variable, and it has not been assigned a value within this scope.**

Comment: That is not a tutorial. It is actually explaining what we are talking about here.

Comment: Ok, my bad. Sorry, RTFM in more datail, do not think C.

Answer (score 0):

keeping it simple, if it was me:

```
//config.php:

<?php
    $folder = 'SomePath';
?>

//script1.php

<?php
 require_once('config.php');

    function doStuff($folder){//parse the variable in to the function

        echo($folder);
    }

    doStuff();
?>
```

Comment: Now that I understood the different scope philosophy I go with the global keyword.

Comment: global is generally NOT recommended. to easy to overwrite other variables hard to maintain, better to keep to tight scoping. but if these are really globlas consider constants: http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php

Comment: Be aware of course that in this example, $folder is not being passed (note: passed, not parsed) in to the function. It is also a good idea to set a default value for your function parameters ( `function doStuff($folder = 'defaultFolderName'){`) or to check if they're `empty()` before attempting to use them.